# How to Remove / Replace Character from PySpark List

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am very new to Python/PySpark and currently using it with Databricks.
I have the following list

```
dummyJson= [
 ('{"name":"leo", "object" : ["191.168.192.96", "191.168.192.99"]}',), 
 ('{"name":"anne", "object" : ["191.168.192.103", "191.168.192.107"]}',),
]
```

When I tried to

`jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(dummyJson)`
then
put it in dataframe
`spark.read.json(jsonRDD)`

it does not parse the JSON correctly.  The resulting dataframe is one column with `_corrupt_record` as the header.

Looking at the elements in dummyJson, it looks like there are extra / unnecessary comma just before the closing parantheses on each element/record.

How can I remove this comma from each of the element of this list?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can fix the input format at the source, that would be ideal.

But for your given case, you may fix it by taking the objects out of the tuple.

```
>>> dJson = [i[0] for i in dummyJson]
>>> jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(dJson)
>>> jsonDF = spark.read.json(jsonRDD)
>>> jsonDF.show()
+----+--------------------+
|name|              object|
+----+--------------------+
| leo|[191.168.192.96, ...|
|anne|[191.168.192.103,...|
+----+--------------------+
```